# Adapting GCS_Auth code example to Google Calendar

Tags: google-oauth

I created a [GitHub repo](https://github.com/mslinn/GoogleOauthPlay) for an sbt project that contains a [modified GCS_Auth code example](https://github.com/mslinn/GoogleOauthPlay/blob/master/app/service/GoogleCalendarAuth.java). I am modifying it so it works with Google Calendar. When I run this project as a console app, I get an OAuth token back valid for 3600 seconds, which is terrific.

My question is: What else must I do in order to enable the app to create a new calendar for a user, and to modify and delete events in the user's calendar? The user will create events in the calendar created by the app. I understand there is an 'enterprise setting' but have not been able to find documentation on what that actually means. From the [OAuth Overview](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=61017): *"An application that has the OAuth consumer key and secret (roughly equivalent to a role account username and password) is allowed to act as any user in the domain when accessing Google Data APIs."* I found "Additional Claims" on [this page](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount) and I'm puzzling it out.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that this capability is only possible if each user accesses a Google Calendar via a domain that is administered via Google's services. Random gmail accounts are not intended to be able to grant write permission to service apps. Unfortunately, this does not meet my project's needs and I will have to write my own Calendar facility.